# Adding and using developer user account in iTunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, roles

How does adding a new user with developer role to iTunes connect works? 
I've just added a new user to iTunes connect to upload a new build version of the app. So I added his email address, name and surname. He accepted the invitation.

How does this person access my iTunes account to upload the new build of the app?
As he accepted the invitation can he now log in and simply upload the app? Or does he need anything else? 
How does this process work?
Thanks.

Comment: When they log in to iTunesConnect they will see the teams that they are a member of (including yours) and can select the one they want to use.

Comment: “How does this person access my iTunes account” He doesn’t. He uses HIS account. “Or does he need anything else” He needs an Apple ID, but he has that, or you would not have gotten thru the process.

Comment: The developer after logging in to itunes asked me to give him permission in itunes to create certificate - is it necessary? Thanks.